# Using two types for one variable. Typescript

Tags: typescript

Transferred js typescript, faced with the problem. The following function works with two types of data, I see this error:

```
Property 'dateTime' does not exist on type 'Operation | OperationCreated'. 
Property 'dateTime' does not exist on type 'OperationCreated'
```

```js
type DateTime = {
  date: string;
};

type Operation = {
  dateTime: DateTime;
};

type OperationCreated = {
  createdDate: string;
};

const sortByDate = (o1: Operation | OperationCreated, o2: Operation | OperationCreated) =>
  stringToMillisecond(o1.createdDate || o1.dateTime.date) - stringToMillisecond(o2.createdDate || o2.dateTime.date);
```

Making the first steps in typescript, please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript does not perceive `o1.createdDate || o1.dateTime.date` as valid for a few reasons:

- The biggest one in terms of runtime impact is that you presume that  `o1.createdDate` will only be [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) if it is `undefined`.  But the empty string is also falsy.   If someone calls this:

  ```
  sortByDate({ createdDate: "" }, { createdDate: "" });
  ```

  then you will end up calling `stringToMillisecond(undefined)`, which I would suspect is an error.  So I would give up on using a falsy check on possibly-`string` values here.
- The TypeScript compiler does not let you read a property value of a union type unless every member of the union contains a (possibly optional) property with that key.  So `o1.createdDate` is an error unless you can *narrow* `o1` to a `OperationCreated` *first*, by [differentiating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) between the possible values.  One way to do this is to [use the `in` operator](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256), like:

  ```
  "createdDate" in o1 ? o1.createdDate : o1.dateTime.date; // no error
  ```

  This works because the compiler uses the `in` check to narrow `o1` to `OperationCreated` in the "then" clause of the ternary operator, or to `OperationDefault` in the "else" clause.

So the most straightforward fix I could imagine here is:

```
const sortByDate = (
  o1: Operation | OperationCreated,
  o2: Operation | OperationCreated
) =>
  stringToMillisecond("createdDate" in o1 ? o1.createdDate : o1.dateTime.date) -
  stringToMillisecond("createdDate" in o2 ? o2.createdDate : o2.dateTime.date);
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!  [Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsCAVAlgW2gXigbwFBRQAmCEAXFAM7ABOKAdgOYDceAvq3qJFAPKQ0EKAPb0o2fIRKJUGCvBnoIrDni7ho-CIOAj6AYRoRSRcbgJQAxkZMLyVWgxbtOl0dSrCawAEIg7ZgAUFsIAjBRaOnpQAD58AkKihsaIRAA0IQBMEQm6orHx2okGNql4AJTiAHwW1HRMSMIAsigANq0olBBu9ESBAETWKRBEdv1QDFBhUAD8U6EAdEO2pFAUYQvSyEqbpJUAtLWODc1tHV09fYOlI2MTYsKZs1OZSzejq+uvW7IQu4jlThEbqtOBGKAAMwArvRLHkxHUnI0Wu1Ot1RH0AB4URFMcoUehQtAAI20nEoXl8-lIgRwVnedgo-XGbDSuHpww+iCZLMBeCAA)

Answer (score 1):

This error is because the compiler doesn't know if `o1` and `o2` are `Operation` or `OperationCreated`. You may use [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).

My solution (to clean)

```js
interface DateTime {
  date: string;
}

interface OperationDefault {
  type: 'default';
  dateTime: DateTime;
}

interface OperationCreated {
  type: 'created';
  createdDate: string;
}

type Operation = OperationDefault | OperationCreated;

const sortByDate = (o1: Operation, o2: Operation) => {
  const d1 = o1.type === 'default' ? o1.dateTime.date : o1.createdDate;
  const d2 = o2.type === 'default' ? o2.dateTime.date : o2.createdDate;

  return stringToMillisecond(d1) - stringToMillisecond(d2);
};
```

Comment: What are you going to do if you have 5 types of data? Are you going to add 'if, if' if if if?

Comment: If there is 5 types of data, and there is no common fields well yes, you can't guess where is the wanted data. In your case a switch may be more appropriate, I just put a quick solution that show the concept of discriminated unions which is a good solution for the author issue.

Comment: But if you have a better solution @Dezigo I'm really open to see it (no irony).

Answer (score -1):

Use an interface instead of a type literal

```
    interface DateTime {
        date: string;
    }

    interface Operation {
        dateTime: DateTime;
    }

    interface OperationCreated {
        createdDate: string;
    }

    const sortByDate = (
        o1: Operation | OperationCreated,
        o2: Operation | OperationCreated
    ) =>
        stringToMillisecond((o1 as any).createdDate || (o1 as any).dateTime.date) -
        stringToMillisecond((o2 as any).createdDate || (o2 as any).dateTime.date);
```

Comment: Cast to `any` and remove the typing cannot be a good solution :(

Comment: Interfaces are generally preferred over type literals because interfaces can be implemented, extended and merged.

Comment: Ok I don't criticize the choice of using interface instead of types, I'm Ok with that. What I don't like is (only) the use of `as any` which destroy the typing.

Comment: What if I add an other Operation to possible ones in the function ? Even if this new type is not handled, there will be no errors from the compiler.

Comment: Any is a solution for a mixed types, you just need to use it carefully. Otherwise, there are many different ways how to it